Mathplotlib FuncAnimate in tkinter Window
I have a Question concerning putting a Mathplotlib Animation in a Tkinter window. I have found a few answers, but they all seem to be using much more difficult plots.
I have this really easy Plot, that worked like this:
values = []

fig = Figure()        
y = [i**2 for i in range(101)]
plt = fig.add_subplot(111)

def Plot(i):
    values.append(communication._GetLiveData()[0])
    
    plt.cla()
    plt.plot(values)

ani = FuncAnimation(plt.gcf(), Plot, interval=45)

Plot = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, master = PlaceFramePlot)
Plot.draw()
Plot.get_tk_widget().pack(side=TOP, fill=BOTH, expand=True)
toolbar = NavigationToolbar2Tk(Plot,PlaceFramePlot)
toolbar.update()

It worked really well without live data, but now I don't see anything in the Plot.
Does anybody know how to simply view the Live Data in this chart?

I can't post this as an answer because it's AI generated, but it is likely the solution to your problem https://chatgpt.com/share/66f2e937-7844-800e-abc1-bab9bcf1b4fc
